# Is there a program in windows which can search menu items like Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, search

In unity dash, you can search commands in menu bar of a program, is there a similar program on windows?

Comment: Please [read this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software) and [edit] your question.

Comment: @JanDoggen The requested feature seems clear to me, without having ever used the Unity dashboard.